# How do I use FIND function in VBA with search sting as a Relative Reference?

Tags: excel, vba

Here's an image with Excel sample data. Columns used are A, B, F & G.

[image]

I am trying to find Part from a Column F into Column A to see if it is in Column A or not.

I know that I can use `FIND` Function in VBA with (`What:="Jane Doe"`) with a double quotes text. But, is it possible to use a relative reference such as `ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1).Value` within the `FIND` function in VBA?

```vb
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim ECOCell As Range
          
    Range("G2").Select
        
    Set SearchRange = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        
    Set ECOCell = SearchRange.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> ""
        If ECOCell Is Nothing Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "No"
        Else
            ActiveCell.Value = "Yes"
        End If
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select     
    Loop    
End Sub
```

Comment: Type `=SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH("*"&F2&"*",A$2:A$5), 0)) > 0` into G2, press [Ctrl+Shit+Enter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) and drag the result down.

Comment: In O365 `=IF(ISERROR(XLOOKUP("*" & TRIM(F2) & "*",$A$2:$A$5,$A$2:$A$5,,2)),"No","Yes")`.  Added `TRIM` to cell reference to remove the space before _Part H_.

Comment: Note that `xlookup` requires Office 365 subscription though.

Comment: What seperates these parts in column A, simple spaces? Also, what version of Excel are you using, and are you open for non-VBA alternatives?

Comment: @JvdV Not just the spaces. Part numbers look actually like "310-00078", "TMF12345", "N000083", or anything like that.

Comment: Can you actually update the question with that information to make it a more [mcve]

Comment: @GSerg Thanks. It works; but, I'd still ask you guys the same question. Is there a way to do with a FIND(What:=ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1).Value) as a relative reference? I mean, my list is 130,000 rows long. VBA code takes approximately 12 minutes to search all one by one. This formula takes some load as well; though still have to see how long. Thanks.

Comment: If you are asking whether you can execute a single Find that will find separate results for each cell from the source range, then no, you can't. You can speed up your VBA code significantly by [getting rid of the `Select`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683), but it's going to fundamentally perform a separate Find per source cell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reference a cell rather than a text string.

There's a few things wrong with your code though.
I take it `ActiveCell` will be looking at each cell in column F.  I'd look in column G and put the Yes/No offset to that.
There's a few problems with using `Select` & `Active` for which I'll point you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) post.

`End(xlDown)` could also cause problems if there's a gap in your data.  Best to start from the bottom and work up.

Your FIND doesn't step through the values in column G either.  It looks like it uses the first result against all the values.
It's also looking at `xlWhole` so will never find Part A, B, C, F or G as they share the cell with other parts (this could cause problems in itself if you have *Part A* and *Part ABCD*).

Try this code:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim PartsRange As Range
    Dim Part As Range
    Dim ECOCell As Range
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set SearchRange = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        Set PartsRange = .Range("F2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))
        
        For Each Part In PartsRange
            Set ECOCell = SearchRange.Find(What:=Trim(Part), After:=.Range("A2"), LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            
            If Not ECOCell Is Nothing Then
                Part.Offset(, 1) = "Yes"
            Else
                Part.Offset(, 1) = "No"
            End If
        Next Part
    End With

End Sub
```